# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status g++ 12 Ubuntu 20.4.4

Tags: c++, linux, g++, ubuntu-20.04

I am working with some code that requires g++12 I could not find a better way to install g++ 12 on Ubuntu 20.4.4 so I installed it using homebrew. When I run g++-12 --version I get

> g++-12 (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0 Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software
> Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying
> conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
> FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

When I try to compile any program using g++-12 I get the error

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status

I have tried adding a -L and -I flags that point to lib and include folders of the homebrew install of g++ 12 but this does not seem to help.

```
g++-12 -std=gnu++20 main.cpp track.cpp -o track 
g++-12 -o hello HelloWorld.cpp
```

Comment: What library are you trying to link with `-lm`? Can you show us full compilation command you use or CMakeLists/make/etc that you use?

Comment: I'm not trying to link with anything it just happens when I try to compile anything. I added some compile examples to the question